# Bash get exit status of command when 'set -e' is active?

Tags: bash

I generally have `-e` set in my Bash scripts, but occasionally I would like to run a command and get the return value.

Without doing the `set +e; some-command; res=$?; set -e` dance, how can I do that?

Comment: Because of problems just like this one, I would recommend NOT using `set -e`  Here are some more examples:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Gotta disagree.  When using bash for configuring systems or other, actual work, `set -e` is essential for showing correctness.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

From the `bash` manual:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is [...] part of any command executed in a && or || list [...].

So, just do:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

foo() {
  # exit code will be 0, 1, or 2
  return $(( RANDOM % 3 ))
}

ret=0
foo || ret=$?
echo "foo() exited with: $ret"
```

Example runs:

```
$ ./foo.sh
foo() exited with: 1
$ ./foo.sh
foo() exited with: 0
$ ./foo.sh
foo() exited with: 2
```

This is the canonical way of doing it.

Comment: You probably want to initialize ret=0 before you do that, in case the command succeeds. Some of them do :)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth -- I had a `ret=0` before `foo || ret=$?` so it would show the case where it succeeded.  I actually tested it multiple times (`for i in $(seq 30); do echo '$ ./foo.sh'; /tmp/stack.sh ; done`) and copy-pasted some results.

Comment: @TheDoctorWhat Sorry, I overlooked that. I have rolled back to your edit. Thanks :-)

Comment: No problem. I've made mistakes that needed catching plenty of times.

Comment: Alternatively, one could do:

`foo || ret=$? ; echo "foo() exited with: ${ret:-0}"`

Comment: this answer is not correct.  here is example code that does what the answer suggests and then does not exit when there is an error. `(set -eu; func() { cd directory_that_does_not_exist; echo "should not reach here"; return 0; }; exitcode=0; func||exitcode=$?; echo $exitcode; )` . here is example code that demonstrates correctly exiting when there is an error: `(set -eu; func() { cd directory_that_does_not_exist; echo "should not reach here"; return 0; }; set +e; (set -e; func); exitcode=$?; set -e; echo $exitcode; )`

Answer (score 16):

as an alternative

```
ans=0
some-command || ans=$?
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe try running the commands in question in a subshell, like this?

```
res=$(some-command > /dev/null; echo $?)
```

Comment: Of course we're abusing stdout for passing the exitcode, which has its downsides.

Answer (score 1):

Given behavior of shell described at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside-subshells-with-parenthesis-followed-by-an-or) it's possible to use following construct:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

{ custom_command; rc=$?; } || :

echo $rc
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use simple `if`. It is a bit longer, but fully supported by bash, i.e. that the command can return non-zero value, but the script doesn't exit even with `set -e`. See it in this simple script:

```
#! /bin/bash -eu

f () {
  return 2
}

if f;then
  echo Command succeeded
else
  echo Command failed, returned: $?
fi
echo Script still continues.
```

When we run it, we can see that script still continues after non-zero return code:

```
$ ./test.sh 
Command failed, returned: 2
Script still continues.
```

Answer (score -3):

Use a wrapper function to execute your commands:

```
function __e {
    set +e
    "$@"
    __r=$?
    set -e
}

__e yourcommand arg1 arg2
```

And use `$__r` instead of `$?`:

```
if [[ __r -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "failed"
fi
```

Another method to call commands in a pipe, only that you have to quote the pipe. This does a safe eval.

```
function __p {
    set +e
    local __A=() __I
    for (( __I = 1; __I <= $#; ++__I )); do
        if [[ "${!__I}" == '|' ]]; then
            __A+=('|')
        else
            __A+=("\"\$$__I\"")
        fi
    done
    eval "${__A[@]}"
    __r=$?
    set -e
}
```

Example:

```
__p echo abc '|' grep abc
```

And I actually prefer this syntax:

```
__p echo abc :: grep abc
```

Which I could do with

```
...
        if [[ ${!__I} == '::' ]]; then
...
```

Comment: @DavidWolever Please tell me what you think about this solution.

Comment: This will e.g. break on I/O redirection.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I doubt that. Example?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Where is it then? Can you give me an example command that would fail instead?

Comment: `cat foo | grep bar >/dev/null 2>&1`. You cannot store complex commands in variables, thus `"$@"` will not work for all use cases. Disclaimer: I do use this myself sometimes, but then I know how those commands look like and that they don't work for arbitrary complex invocations. This is an example of where it's a bad idea. For further info see the link.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I guess it does have trouble with piped commands as the function was only intended to run a single one. But only with that. It would save you from running two-line commands everytime and it's simpler.

Comment: How is it simpler than a one-line `r=0; command || r=$?` which works as expected? Oh well, not trying to start argument here, I don't even use `set -e` myself since its implementation is really stupid. Whatever works ;-)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Well I do don't like the idea of using `-e` as well :) Let's just let the OP decide on that I guess. And no worries.

Comment: Why people call functions and variables like `__function` `__variable` this is so hard to read. Is that python-ish way to say it's private? If so it's strange as `__r` is a global variable. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @tamerlaha Yes this was an old answer. I don't like the idea of having a lowercase variable like __r set as a global variable as well. Should have been __R at least as I use all-caps for globals. I don't remember why I used a prefix for the function. Perhaps I just couldn't think of a proper name or was lazy.  Prefixed local variables on the other hand are useful for avoiding collision when they are the functions accept reference variable arguments.  Bash 4.4's `declare -n` feature was not safe on collisions at least.