# How to check exit code with NOT in Bash? (if ! ... $?)

Tags: bash, exit-code

What's the "right" way to access the exit code of an unsuccessful command?

I ask because I just learned the hard way that the behavior is extremely unintuitive:

If you do

```
if ! false; then
    echo $?
fi
```

then it prints `0`, whereas if you do

```
if false; then
    :
else
    echo $?
fi
```

it prints `1`, despite the fact that the two seem logically equivalent.

The second one is obviously a workaround, but is there a more proper way to do this?

Note that **I obviously don't want a command with collateral damage here**.
For example, merely doing

```
false
if [ 0 -ne $? ]; then
    echo $?
fi
```

would have entirely different behavior when `set -e` is in effect.

Comment: @Cyrus: That doesn't always work (e.g. if `set -e` is in effect).

Comment: @anubhava: See my previous comment.

Comment: This might help: `! false; echo $?; false; echo $?`

Comment: @Mehrdad: That should be part of your question not in comments

Comment: [Bash get exit status of command when 'set -e' is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621990/bash-get-exit-status-of-command-when-set-e-is-active)

Comment: @Mehrdad, what's unintuitive or surprising about it? `!` has its own exit status; if `true` has an exit status of 0 (truthy!), `! true` has an exit status that's falsey.

Comment: @anubhava: Added, but I'd have thought it'd go without saying that I don't want extra behavior that I didn't ask for... can you reopen now?

Comment: And yeah, [`set -e` is an entirely awful idea and should never be used by anyone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

Comment: If you don't want extra behavior, **don't use `set -e`**. It's a huge collection of hacks and workarounds, and is moreover [different between shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) and releases of the same shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm **well aware of the numerous pitfalls**, but using `&&` has its own pitfalls, and in any case, even I can't always dictate to the other authors of a script whether `set -e` is in effect or not. I need a command that works whether it's in effect or not, regardless of whether I enjoy it.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Ah, I guess I need an extra variable then. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are the pitfalls of `foo_rc=0; foo || foo_rc=$?`?